# How to access information using Rails in Join Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models:

```
USERS
has_many :celebrations
has_many :boards, :through => :celebrations

BOARDS
has_many :celebrations
has_many :users, :through => :celebrations


CELEBRATIONS
:belongs_to :user
:belongs_to :board
```

I understand that I create a third join table and model called "Celebrations" which does not require an ID.

```
   create_table :, :id => false do |t|
      t.column :board_id,        :int, :null => false
      t.column :user_id,         :int, :null => false 
      t.column :role,            :string, :null => false
      t.column :token,           :string
      t.timestamps
      end
  end
```

How do I access the information?

user.celebrations.role
user.celeberations.token

user.boards
board.users

Thanks in advance. I understand its a real newbie question.

Comment: For `has_many :through`, you need to have `id` (primary key) (For HABTM, you need not have.). To access the information, what you have defined is correct(`user.celebrations.role`, `user.celeberations.token`, `user.boards`, `board.users`). Remove `:id => false` from the migration. You can also say `t.string :role` instead of `t.column :role, :string` in the migration.

Comment: Thank you I will do all that you have suggested. Thanks for your response. It really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can but if the join table has additional attributes then you should convert it to the full model. I mean to create a new Rails model with `id, article_id, author_id` and additional fields like `role`.

This is the Rails way of implementing such things. There is a small overhead of making the join table a little bit bigger. However with full join model it is possible to use standard Rails functions to create and update that model.

As far I remember `has_many :through` option was added to support better join models.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I was not sure about taking the ID off of the join table when I wrote it. Now I understand that I need it. Thanks for your help.